# Guessing which .qml goes with every layer of a project

Tags: qgis, qml

I have a project in QGIS (v3.8) containing 25 layers with different simbology. This simbology I know it is associated to a specific .qml file that is in a folder of my user profile in QGIS.
Is there any way to know which .qml goes with every layer?
I have opened the properties of every layer but i don't see anywhere where I can look for it.

Comment: The symbology is stored within the project file. If you want to transfer single layers to another project using the same symbology, go to the layer properties, hit the "style" button at the middle bottom and choose `save as default`. This saves a `.qml` at the location of the shapefile.

Comment: I have to modify the simbology of a few layers but keep the same .qml file with the same name... That's why I want to know which .qml goes with every layer. Besides, the layers come from a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: I guess you could ask the person who created the `.qml` or take a look in the documentation they did?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible :(  And the documentation is very poor... Everything is against me!!

Comment: You could create new `.qml` with either logical names and/or a sound documentation -that would be the most efficient way I guess.

Comment: That would be the logical steps... But orders are to keep everything as it is...

Comment: I went through a project file of mine which contains shapes which have a default style attached to them - no mention of where said style is saved. So I'd suggest you tell your boss you're not able to comply due to non-existent documentation - unless they know some trick you'd go with a new, logical naming and the creation of a documentation. Does your boss know anything about QGIS?

Comment: Nothing at all... But i'll try what you suggest... Thanks for your help!